# Finding orphaned records in MySQL using LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, orphan

I'm trying to find distinct orphaned menu_item records using LEFT JOINS then checking for NULL values.

The query below is returning results that aren't actually orphans.  mitem_id is a primary key for the menu_item table and a foreign key for the price_info table.  pinfo_id is the primary key for the price_info table and a foreign key orderdetails table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT mi.mitem_id, descr 
FROM menu_item mi 
    LEFT JOIN price_info pi ON pi.menu_item = mi.mitem_id 
    LEFT JOIN orderdetails od ON od.price_info = pi.pinfo_id 
WHERE od.detail_id IS NULL;
```

One of the records returned looks like this:

```
+----------+------------------+
| mitem_id | descr            |
+----------+------------------+
|      926 | Alameda Pale Ale |
+----------+------------------+
```

How I know it's not an orphan is because when I run the query:

```
SELECT od.detail_id 
FROM orderdetails od 
   INNER JOIN price_info pi ON pi.pinfo_id = od.price_info 
    INNER JOIN menu_item mi ON mi.mitem_id = pi.menu_item 
WHERE mi.mitem_id = 926;
```

It returns a set of records:

```
+-----------+
| detail_id |
+-----------+
|    142830 |
|    142876 |
|    143394 |
|    143610 |
```

Why is it returning results that aren't orphaned?

Comment: LEFT JOIN returns all entries that are in the "left" table, that may or may not necessarily be in the "right" table. It will still return records that are in the "right" table because they are in the "left" table as well.

Comment: If you're using OUTER JOINs then the sequence of your JOINS is relevant for the result. Your queries are very different. You should add minimal sample data for your other tables.

Comment: Is it possible that the join results in at least one row from orderdetails, where detail_id is NULL? That is, maybe there are multiple rows from orderdetails that match menu_item and price_info, and at least one is not NULL

Answer (score 2):

Kane was correct in that records were being returned that were not null.  The many to many relationship between menu_item and price_info prevented me from using LEFT JOIN WHERE NULL to find orphaned records.  I ended up having to change my query to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT mi.mitem_id, descr FROM menu_item mi
WHERE mi.mitem_id NOT IN 
(SELECT mi.mitem_id FROM menu_item mi 
INNER JOIN price_info pi ON pi.menu_item = mi.mitem_id 
INNER JOIN orderdetails od ON od.price_info = pi.pinfo_id)
```